# Can somebody explain the `clean` dependency in this gulpfile?

Tags: angularjs, gulp, del

Trying to study https://github.com/jhades/angularjs-gulp-example/blob/master/gulpfile.js, and I have noticed that for the task `build` there is a dependency `clean`. However, for most of the other definitions `clean` is also specified as a dependency! So if I run `build` it will run `clean`, but then what about `build-css` and `build-template-cache` which both also have `clean` dependencies, etc... will it also run the `clean` for each of those dependencies? So basically will running the one command `gulp build` end up running `clean` more than once... wiping out the output from other dependencies.... or will running `clean` the first time explicitly satisfy the dependency for the other dependencies and prevent `clean` from running again!?

Any pointers will be appreciated.

## Please Note

I am NOT asking about what the proper cleaning techniques are! I am specifically asking about the link that I posted... and how IT is handling the `clean` task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clean a project correctly with gulp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24396659/how-to-clean-a-project-correctly-with-gulp)

Comment: @Claies I briefly read the link... so, thank you. However, I am not asking about how to clean the project correctly. My question is specifically to do with the link I posted... and how it handles the cleaning. I just need to understand its flow.. because it apparently seems to be running fine.

Comment: basically, the build is done in a pipeline, but the `clean` is not part of the pipeline.  because `clean` is called as a dependency to each task, it must be done before the task is run, but each task then returns a promise object.  The net effect is that the cleans are all run in the front end of the chain.

Comment: the only conflict really occurs if you happen to be using `watch` to trigger one of those tasks that has a dependency on `clean`, which would cause the `clean` to kick off during the watch, and potentially remove unwanted files, which is the problem that was happening in the link I referenced.

Comment: @Claies I see. Thank you.

Comment: I've put in an edit that makes it super minimal. While it may not but accepted, if you feel as if the edit wasn't what you were looking, go ahead revert it, but please strip out some of the unneeded details.

Answer (score 1):

## Dependencies

`Dependencies` in a gulp file just say that it has to have run before it at least once. For example this code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('main', ['b', 'a'], function() {
  return gulp;
});

gulp.task('a', ['b'], function() {
  return gulp;
});

gulp.task('b', ['a'], function() {
  return gulp;
});
```

Will run like this:

- `main`
- `a`
- `b`

Not:

- `main`
- `a`
- `b`
- `a`
- `b`

Repeating infinitely.

## Dependencies execution order

However, it could just as easily be run in the order `main`, `b`, then `a`. This is because of [synchronous tasks](http://schickling.me/synchronous-tasks-gulp/) in `gulp`. The dependencies have to run before the task asynchronously, but they run together or synchronously, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/748189/5461005) explains the difference between synchronous and asynchronous.

To avoid this you can use this code in `Gulp 4`:

```
gulp.task('main', function() {
  gulp.series('a', 'b');
});
```

This will always run in the order `main`, `a`, `b`
But below that, you need to use the [`run-sequence`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence) package. Here's an example:

```
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
gulp.task('main', function() {
  runSequence('a', 'b');
})
```

Comment: I thought the dependency order was not necessarily "in order" because they apparently run asynchronously. Isn't that true?